# prevent image from continuing to grow once screen reaches a certain width

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I currently have a hero image I am developing in a react application.  I have successfully made the image responsive for smaller screen sizes.  the issue I am running into is that once the screen becomes larger at a certain point the image begins zooming in until you can only see a portion of the image.  The desired effect I am going for is that on screen sizes higher than 1650px I would like the full image to be displayed no white space, and for the image to stop zooming in and growing.

my css code is as follows:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}
.container .container-background {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.container-background {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 980px;
}

.container-background-img {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 280px;
  max-height: 980px;
  min-height: 60vh;
  height: 644px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center right;
  position: relative;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.container .content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* CODE ADDED */
#navbar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
  .container-background-img {
    min-height: auto;
    height: 644px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  .container-background-img {
    height: 405px;
  }
}
```

my jsx code is as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="container-background">
          <img
            id="rob"
            src="https://i.imgur.com/aDExJLE.png"
            alt="bg"
            className="container-background-img"
          />
        </div>
        <div id="content" className="content">
          The CTA DATA
        </div>
        <div id="navbar">Navbar GOES HERE !!!</div>
      </div>
      {/* I would like this section to be below the image!!!! */}
      <div>I want this div to be under the image!!!</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

attached is a code sandbox for debugging: https://codesandbox.io/s/issue-react-forked-7pq32?file=/src/App.js:0-655

Comment: You can try something like this, [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/issue-react-forked-ytxqc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark), with `background-attachment: fixed;` which  seems to help a bit to reduce the fluctuation in the image's view. Another option would be separating the building (your focus point) from the sky background with Photoshop, the building image would be placed within the header with the sky as  background.

Comment: the issue I have with this solution is the lack of responsiveness when resizing the screen.  What i have is responsive for small screens but causes issues with large screens for some reason

Comment: Unless you prevent your container from continuously growing with the window the image will always keep zooming. You can consider  `object-fit` in case you are using an `<img>` or apply different image source depending on the screen size: 

`<picture>
  <source media="(max-width: 799px)" srcset="elva-480w-close-portrait.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="elva-800w.jpg">
  <img src="elva-800w.jpg" alt="Chris standing up holding his daughter Elva">
</picture>`

Comment: Though both `object-fit` and the `source media` do not work well on IE, at least I always avoided object-fit. If I were you, I would prefer to go with css media queries and `background-image`.

Comment: I am using object fit, but how do you prevent the container from growing without there being white space on large screens

Comment: You can not really fully avoid any white space (unless a different background on a parent container or body) if you do `max-width: 1900px; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;` on your main container, It will stop your content box from growing, but also leave void at the left and right side of your content. Bootstrap's .container and .container-fluid are both good examples